# Objective C - Seconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and a given date

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone

An app I'm developing needs to match the functionality of Javascript's Date.valueOf(). However the values between the Javascript and Objective-c below are different. What am I doing wrong?

**Javascript:**

```
var d = new Date('2016-08-21T09:00:00')
console.debug(d.valueOf()/1000);
// Result: 1471734000
```

**Objective-c:**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd H:mm:ss"];
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[gregorianCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDateComponents *startDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[startDateComponents setYear:1970];
[startDateComponents setMonth:1];
[startDateComponents setDay:1];
[startDateComponents setHour:0];
[startDateComponents setMinute:0];
[startDateComponents setSecond:0];
[startDateComponents setNanosecond:0];
NSDate *startDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:startDateComponents];
NSString* startDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate];
NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[endDateComponents setYear:2016];
[endDateComponents setMonth:8];
[endDateComponents setDay:21];
[endDateComponents setHour:9];
[endDateComponents setMinute:0];
[endDateComponents setSecond:0];
[endDateComponents setNanosecond:0];
NSDate *endDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];
NSString* endDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:endDate];
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
distanceBetweenDates -= timezoneoffset;
printf("Seconds between %s and %s = %f\n", [startDateString UTF8String], [endDateString UTF8String], distanceBetweenDates);
// Result: Seconds between 1970-01-01 0:00:00 and 2016-08-21 9:00:00 = 1471734000
```

**Edit:** Updated JS date constructor as per comment.
**Edit:** Updated Objective-c to account for time zone offset. There is now no difference in results.

Comment: The Javascript value you posted isn't correct for August 21, 2016. The Objective-C value is correct. It matches (close enough) what I get running the `date +%s` command on my computer.

Comment: FYI - The Javascript Date command expects the month to be zero based so you've actually specified the date September 21, 2016.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I've edited to fix the JS date constructor. Also accounted for the Objective-c time zone offset. The results are now identical.

Comment: You can use property `timeIntervalSince1970` of `NSDate` (`endDate. timeIntervalSince1970`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments by rmaddy pointing out the zero based month in Javascript. I was able to resolve this by adjusting the JS date constructor and accounting for Objective-c's time zone offset.